# How to access elements of json array using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array like this

```
AlreadySaved:[  
{  
  "SNO":1,
  "SNUMBER":"827",
  "STARTDATE":"11/12/2016",
  "STARTTIME":"03:06:50 PM",
  "ITEMNAME":"KBand",
  "ITEMCODE":"KB2541",
  "ITEMSKUNAME":"Band",
  "ITEMSKUCODE":"BT102",
  "SALESRATE":100.0,
  "PURCHASERATE":5.0,
  "DOE":"~",
  "STOCKQTY":2.0,
  "PHYSICALQTY":1.0
}
]
```

I need to fetch value of PHYSICALQTY and display it in alert.I am new to jquery/javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add what you have tried so far to achieve what you want and include in OP where you got stuck. Also your sample is not valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access json like normal objects in js via dot notation.

```
var json = {"STOCKQTY":2.0,"PHYSICALQTY":1.0};

console.log(json.PHYSICALQTY);
```

If you Have saved this json under another object You need to go deeper, eg.

```
var response = {AlreadySaved: [{"STOCKQTY":2.0,"PHYSICALQTY":1.0}] };

console.log(response.AlreadySaved[0].PHYSICALQTY);
```

Please remember also that in some cases You may have json (eg from response) as string  not object.

```
console.log(typeof someJson); //string
```

In that cases You need to parse this string into json

```
var json = JSON.parse(someJsonAsString);
```

Happy hacking!

Comment: actually, if it were JSON, it'd be just a string, so you can't access json like normal objects at all

Comment: I wrote that in some cases You can get this not parsed which will be a string. So You need to use JSON.parse in that cases

Comment: no, you said you can access JSON like an Object ... except JSON is a string, and an Object is an Object

Comment: OK, You made Your point. I agree with You

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json[0].PHYSICALQTY`

```js
var json = [{
  "SNO": 1,
  "SNUMBER": "827",
  "STARTDATE": "11/12/2016",
  "STARTTIME": "03:06:50 PM",
  "ITEMNAME": "KBand",
  "ITEMCODE": "KB2541",
  "ITEMSKUNAME": "Band",
  "ITEMSKUCODE": "BT102",
  "SALESRATE": 100.0,
  "PURCHASERATE": 5.0,
  "DOE": "~",
  "STOCKQTY": 2.0,
  "PHYSICALQTY": 1.0
}];

document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML=json[0].PHYSICALQTY;
```

```html
<div>
PHYSICALQTY:<label id="id1"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not json object.

Json:

```
{AlreadySaved:[{"SNO":1,"SNUMBER":"827","STARTDATE":"11/12/2016","STARTTIME":"03:06:50 PM","ITEMNAME":"KBand","ITEMCODE":"KB2541","ITEMSKUNAME":"Band","ITEMSKUCODE":"BT102","SALESRATE":100.0,"PURCHASERATE":5.0,"DOE":"~","STOCKQTY":2.0,"PHYSICALQTY":1.0}]}
```

In this case you may get your property:
alert(AlreadySaved[0].PHYSICALQTY);

Comment: what you call Json is not valid either - property names need to be in `""` - so, your example SHOULD be `{"AlreadySaved":[ ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this and then get the value. Ouf course if you receive this like a string.

```
var a = '[{"SNO":1,"SNUMBER":"827","STARTDATE":"11/12/2016","STARTTIME":"03:06:50 PM","ITEMNAME":"KBand","ITEMCODE":"KB2541","ITEMSKUNAME":"Band","ITEMSKUCODE":"BT102","SALESRATE":100.0,"PURCHASERATE":5.0,"DOE":"~","STOCKQTY":2.0,"PHYSICALQTY":1.0}]'

var output = JSON.parse(a)

console.log(output[0].PHYSICALQTY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object is not valid, you can check that at http://jsonlint.com/

Once you set it to something like

```
var AlreadySaved =[{"SNO":1,"SNUMBER":"827","STARTDATE":"11/12/2016","STARTTIME":"03:06:50 PM","ITEMNAME":"KBand","ITEMCODE":"KB2541","ITEMSKUNAME":"Band","ITEMSKUCODE":"BT102","SALESRATE":100.0,"PURCHASERATE":5.0,"DOE":"~","STOCKQTY":2.0,"PHYSICALQTY":1.0}] ;
```

you can access it via `AlreadySaved[0]["PHYSICALQTY"]`

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to serialize your object like this;

```
var json_data = JSON.parse(AlreadySaved);
```

and if you know specific data in json_data, you can call with index number like this;

```
var result= json_data[0]["PHYSICALQTY"];
```

Or you can find whatever you want, you can find with foreach;

```
for(var item in json_data) {
   alert(item["PHYSICALQTY"].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
//In case you are getting this from ajax request put "returnObject.Json_Variable" instead of "Json_Variable"
var obj = (JSON.parse("Json_Variable"));
var resultPHYSICALQTY=obj.PHYSICALQTY);
```

Comment: @Shreya, In case you have any query or problem please feel free to ping me and if you find it helpful mark it as answer so it will help others too